# Trouble Returning XML to 2D Array not Looping to next Element

Tags: asp.net, xml, vb.net, linq, multidimensional-array

So, my array is not looping through the next element instead its just returning this.  Am Missing a loop somewhere?

Here is what **mArray** Return now:

```
mArray  {Length=21} String(,)
        (0,0)   "Saturday"  String
        (0,1)   "12:00" String
        (0,2)   "5:00"  String
        (1,0)   "Saturday"  String
        (1,1)   "12:00" String
        (1,2)   "5:00"  String
        (2,0)   "Saturday"  String
        (2,1)   "12:00" String
        (2,2)   "5:00"  String
        (3,0)   "Saturday"  String
        (3,1)   "12:00" String
        (3,2)   "5:00"  String
        (4,0)   "Saturday"  String
        (4,1)   "12:00" String
        (4,2)   "5:00"  String
        (5,0)   "Saturday"  String
        (5,1)   "12:00" String
        (5,2)   "5:00"  String
        (6,0)   "Saturday"  String
        (6,1)   "12:00" String
        (6,2)   "5:00"  String
```

**This is my desired Results:**

```
mArray  {Length=21} String(,)
        (0,0)   "Sunday"  String
        (0,1)   "12:00" String
        (0,2)   "5:00"  String
        (1,0)   "Monday"  String
        (1,1)   "10:00" String
        (1,2)   "8:00"  String
        (2,0)   "Tuesday"  String
        (2,1)   "10:00" String
        (2,2)   "8:00"  String
        (3,0)   "Wednesday"  String
        (3,1)   "10:00" String
        (3,2)   "8:00"  String
        (4,0)   "Thursday"  String
        (4,1)   "10:00" String
        (4,2)   "6:00"  String
        (5,0)   "Friday"  String
        (5,1)   "10:00" String
        (5,2)   "6:00"  String
        (6,0)   "Saturday"  String
        (6,1)   "12:00" String
        (6,2)   "5:00"  String
```

**XML File**  For reference

```
 <BranchHours>
      <Hours>
        <DayOfWeek>Sunday</DayOfWeek>
        <Open>12:00</Open>
        <Close>5:00</Close>
      </Hours>
      <Hours>
        <DayOfWeek>Monday</DayOfWeek>
        <Open>10:00</Open>
        <Close>8:00</Close>
      </Hours>
      <Hours>
        <DayOfWeek>Tuesday</DayOfWeek>
        <Open>10:00</Open>
        <Close>8:00</Close>
      </Hours>
      <Hours>
        <DayOfWeek>Wednesday</DayOfWeek>
        <Open>10:00</Open>
        <Close>8:00</Close>
      </Hours>
      <Hours>
        <DayOfWeek>Thursday</DayOfWeek>
        <Open>10:00</Open>
        <Close>6:00</Close>
      </Hours>
      <Hours>
        <DayOfWeek>Friday</DayOfWeek>
        <Open>10:00</Open>
        <Close>6:00</Close>
      </Hours>
      <Hours>
        <DayOfWeek>Saturday</DayOfWeek>
        <Open>12:00</Open>
        <Close>5:00</Close>
      </Hours>
    </BranchHours>
```

Here is the **Function:**

```vb
Public Shared Function BranchOpenClose(ByVal branchCode As String) As Array
    'set XML URL path
    Dim URLString As String = "url/branchesTesting.xml"
    'load URL Path
    Dim xmlDoc As XDocument = XDocument.Load(URLString)

    'decalre a 2- dimensional array of string as:
    Dim mArray(6, 2) As String

    Dim i As Integer
    '  Dim j As String
    'Find XML Path Using Passed BranchCode variable   & Select Hours Element Values

    Dim Items = From BranchHours In xmlDoc.XPathSelectElements("/BranchesInfo/BranchInfo[BranchId='" & branchCode & "']/BranchHours/Hours") _
        Select DayOfWeek = ((BranchHours.Elements("DayOfWeek").ToArray.Value)), _
        Open = ((BranchHours.Elements("Open").ToArray.Value)), _
        Close = ((BranchHours.Elements("Close").ToArray.Value))

    For Each Hours In Items
        For i = 0 To 6
            mArray(i, 0) = Hours.DayOfWeek
            mArray(i, 1) = Hours.Open
            mArray(i, 2) = Hours.Close
        Next
    Next

    Return mArray
End Function
```

...................................................................................

Comment: Can you not just return Items.ToArray()

Comment: Can you elaborate on Items.ToArray()? I have a feeling its in the For Each Loop but I could be wrong.

Comment: no remove the for loop and just Return Items.ToArray(). See my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the solution I was looking for.
I had a loop inside another loop it goes through each hour, and then goes again from 0 -6.... I just needed a simple counter here instead of the additional FOR.
This is why it rewrote my values over and over again

```
   For Each Hours In Items

                mArray(i, 0) = Hours.DayOfWeek
                mArray(i, 1) = Hours.Open
                mArray(i, 2) = Hours.Close

                i+=1

        Next
```

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

Use anonymous method with xml linq

```
Imports System.Xml
Imports System.Xml.Linq
Module Module1
    Dim FILENAME As String = "c:\temp\test.xml"
    Sub Main()

        Dim doc As XDocument = XDocument.Load(FILENAME)

        Dim results = doc.Descendants("Hours").Select(Function(x) New With { _
           .dayOfWeek = x.Element("DayOfWeek").Value, _
           .open = CType(x.Element("Open"), DateTime),
           .close = CType(x.Element("Close"), DateTime)
       }).ToList()

    End Sub

End Module
```

Here is screen image of results

[image]

Comment: Do your results return a list like this ? mArray  {Length=21} String(,)
(0,0)   "Sunday"  String (0,1)   "12:00" String(0,2)   "5:00"  String
(1,0)   "Monday"  String(1,1)   "10:00" String (1,2)   "8:00"  String
(2,0)   "Tuesday"  String(2,1)   "10:00" String(2,2)   "8:00"  String
(3,0)   "Wednesday"  String (3,1)   "10:00" String .. etc. If not, how would you select Tuesday with only integers like (2,0) using .ToList? I ask because this was my first approach but need to be able to select it like an array.

Comment: Added image of results

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to populate the array yourself, use ToArray():

```
Public Shared Function BranchOpenClose(ByVal branchCode As String) As Array
    'set XML URL path
    Dim URLString As String = "url/branchesTesting.xml"
    'load URL Path
    Dim xmlDoc As XDocument = XDocument.Load(URLString)

    Dim i As Integer
    'Find XML Path Using Passed BranchCode variable   & Select Hours Element Values

    Dim Items = From BranchHours In xmlDoc.XPathSelectElements("/BranchesInfo/BranchInfo[BranchId='" & branchCode & "']/BranchHours/Hours") _
        Select DayOfWeek = ((BranchHours.Elements("DayOfWeek").ToArray.Value)), _
        Open = ((BranchHours.Elements("Open").ToArray.Value)), _
        Close = ((BranchHours.Elements("Close").ToArray.Value))

    Return Items.ToArray()
End Function
```